# Runtime API to collect values in StorageMap

Tags: storage, runtime, frame, api, map

I'm trying to retrieve all values in my StorageMap defined as such in my pallet:

```
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn submitted_tasks)]
pub type SubmittedTasks<T: Config> =
    StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, B3Hash, Task<T>, OptionQuery>;
```

from my runtime api (in runtime/src/lib.rs), currently defined as such and not working:

```
impl pallet_submitter_runtime_api::SubmitterRuntimeApi<Block> for Runtime {
    fn get_submitted_tasks() -> Vec<Vec<u8>> {
        // This macro generated getter only allows me to query one item.
        SubmitterModule::submitted_tasks();

        // This does not compile due to associated item not found
        SubmitterModule::SubmittedTasks.iter_values().collect();
        
        vec![]
    }
}
```

Now from my understanding, if i use the macro generated getter, it's only possible to query one value from the StorageMap, however I would like to iterate over all values to collect them.
How can I achieve this?

Note: the return type will be the vector of encoded Tasks for simplicity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. I added a comment above the line in the code to explain what happens there.

```
impl pallet_submitter_runtime_api::SubmitterRuntimeApi<Block> for Runtime {
    fn get_submitted_tasks() -> Vec<Vec<u8>> {
        // This macro generated getter only allows me to query one item.
        SubmitterModule::submitted_tasks();

        // The return type is Vec<Vec<u8>>, but your StorageMap stores 
        // as value a `Task<T>`. So, you need to first encode this value
        // and then you can collect into a vector. You probably just missed
        // the explicit type to make Rust happy.
        pallet_submitter::SubmittedTasks::<Runtime>::iter_values().map(|v| v.encode()).collect::<Vec<Vec<_>>>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the encoding part is a good tip, however it still complains: "associated item not found in pallet_submitter::Pallet<Runtime>". Referring to the SubmittedTasks, Which makes sense as the StorageMap is technically defined inside the pallet module and not associated with the Pallet struct

Comment: Ahh yeah that makes sense. I edited my answer. Now it should work.

Comment: That is the syntax I was looking for, thanks. Now it works