# How many ways are there to get all items stored in custom pallet

Tags: polkadot-js, storage, storagemap

I would like to know what are the ways and how we can retrieve the all items stored in a custom pallet

I was having data structured in this way

```rust
#[derive(
        Clone, Encode, Decode, Eq, PartialEq, Default, RuntimeDebug, MaxEncodedLen, TypeInfo,
    )]
    pub struct ProvidedConsent<BoundedString> {
        pub _id: BoundedString,
        pub user_id: BoundedString,
        pub business_id: BoundedString,
        pub consent: BoundedVec<Consent<BoundedString>, ConstU32<50>>,
        pub last_updated: u64,
        pub is_active: bool,
        pub is_deleted: bool,
        pub added_on: u64,
    }

    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn consents)]
    pub(super) type UserConsent<T: Config> = StorageDoubleMap<
        _,
        Twox64Concat,
        T::AccountId,
        Twox64Concat,
        BoundedVec<u8, T::StringLimit>,
        ProvidedConsent<BoundedVec<u8, T::StringLimit>>,
        OptionQuery,
    >;

    #[derive(
        Encode, Decode, Clone, PartialEq, Default, Eq, MaxEncodedLen, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo,
    )]
    pub struct Consent<BoundedString> {
        pub key: BoundedString,
        pub is_accepted: bool,
    }
```

I also got to know with polkadot.js we have a way , but for custom pallet how does it work https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.query.other/#map-keys--entries

Also, we have [Runtime API to collect values in StorageMap](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1736/runtime-api-to-collect-values-in-storagemap), we can use it in runtime

But, please can anyone explain how we can implement a retrieve list feature using polkadot.js and using runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case with PolkadotJS it will look like this:

```js
const consents = await api.query.yourpallet.userConsent.entries();
consents.forEach(([key, consent]) => {
  console.log(consent.toHuman());
});
```

And in the Runtime:

```rs
yourpallet::UserConsent::<Runtime>::iter_values().map(|v| v.encode()).collect::<Vec<Vec<_>>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage on how to  access storage from any pallet either it is custom or existing. Substrate already provides APIs for the same and can be called via `api.query.<module>.<method>`.

And if you want to access the storage from polkadot js explorer than you can go to `Developer > Chain State > "pallet"` https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fpolkadot-rpc.dwellir.com#/chainstate